# Next.js middleware to set Axios header

Tags: next.js, jwt, middleware

I'm trying to use Next 12 to add an `Authorization` header to my Axios instance with middleware. However, it doesn't look as though the header is actually being passed into the requests within `getServerSideProps`, and I can't figure out why.

This is what my middleware looks like:

```
import { Client } from 'lib/api/config';
import { AUTH } from 'modules/auth/api/endpoints';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { API_ROOT_URL, AUTH_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY } from 'utils/constants/constants';

const middleware = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const token = req.cookies[AUTH_TOKEN_COOKIE_KEY];
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();

  const response = await fetch(`${API_ROOT_URL}${AUTH.validateToken}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  if (data.statusCode !== 200 && !url.pathname.includes('/login')) {
    url.pathname = '/login';
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  } else {
    Client.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
};

export default middleware;
```

As you can see I'm storing the token in a cookie, getting the token from the `req.cookies` property when a request is made, validating the token, and if it's valid I'm adding it to `Client.defaults.headers`. However, if I make a request to a route I'm getting a 403 error saying that there is no auth header found. Is there something I need to change up to get this going?

As a side not, we're using the WordPress REST API, coupled with this plugin for JWT Authentication:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/#description

Comment: any updates here?

Answer (score -1):

In nextjs all api stuff are done in pages/api folder and quite strictly so.